# How to use Resharper File/Live Templates to Generate Exception Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, resharper

I like to make a lot of custom exceptions for most error cases I run into, instead of say using InvalidOperation all the time.

I recently got Resharper and thought it's template functionality would be my savior, but I can't seem to get what I want out of the File/Live template function.

What I'm trying to do is essentially type this:

```
...
throw new [resharper key combo]MyCustomName[enter]
...
```

and get an exception class named 'MyCustomNameException' in file 'MyCustomNameException.cs'.

Live templates doesn't seem to be the right thing for me -- that expands code inline.
But file templates doesn't seem to either -- it only asks me to specify the name of the file.  Is the file template option as close as I can get to what I want here?

Comment: The best I've got so far is to type out my typename, hit alt-enter on the undefined symbol, hit alt-enter again to move the new class to a new file, and then use alt-insert to generate some constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about adding the 'Exception' part, but if you type the full name and press `ALT` + `ENTER`, ReSharper will offer to 'Create Class 'MyCustomNameException''. The code it creates is:

```
internal class MyCustomNameException : Exception
{
}
```